# Phabricator run GitLab CI build when Review is Accepted

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, phabricator

How can I start a build from Phabricator under specific conditions?

Currently we are using triggers to start a build, but I need to start it when the review is passed in Phabricator.

The flow is: we take the Task from the Review to the Testing, and this is what need to start the trigger which start the build under GitLab.

It is not necessary do the same, if anyone know an other solution or a best practice I am happy to hear.

Comment: It seems to me that you already have a build plan defined in your Phabricator and you just need a new trigger rule. Is it right? If yes, see my answer. if no, please clarify the question, premising that "creating a build plan with Harbormaster to trigger a GitLab CI" deserves a separated question - and also in that case please clarify if you want to trigger something in GitLab, or you just want to read the gitlab-ci.yaml from Phabricator (obviously not supported, since it's GitLab-specific)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said you already have a Build Plan that is triggered on every commit.

Instead, if you want to trigger your Build Plan, only after you Accept a Revision:

Add an Herald rule, to follow your conditions and trigger your Build Plan.

```
Herald > Create Herald Rule > Differential Revisions > Global Rule
```

Then:

Conditions:

- Revision Status = Accepted
- Repository = Your repository

Actions:

- Run Build Plan = Your Build Plan

Example:

[image: Herald revision triger build plan]